# PowerShell Core not playing nicely with jq

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to get all branches from a git repository and store them in a PSObject.  My code works in zsh and bash but not in PowerShell Core.  Looking through the PowerShell documentation ([Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6), and [Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6)), I cannot see anything that I would need to escape.  Since the line works in zsh and bash, I don't think that jq is the problem.

The part of the command that is failing is:

`jq --raw-input --slurp 'split("\n") | map(split("\t")) | .[0:-1]'`

The error is:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
split(\n) | map(split(\t)) | .[0:-1]
jq: 1 compile error
```

The entire command that I'm using is (in bash replace the ` newlines with \ ):

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate:iso8601' `
    refs/heads `
    --format='%(refname:short)%09%(creatordate:rfc)%09%(creator)%09%(committerdate:rfc)%09%(committeremail)' `
    | jq --raw-input --slurp 'split("\n") 
      | map(split("\t")) 
      | .[0:-1] 
      | map( {
        "branchName": .[0], 
        "AuthorDate": .[1], 
        "Author": .[2], 
        "CommitDate": .[3], 
        "Committer": .[4]
      })'
```

My PowerShell Core version is:
6.2.1
I am running from a Mac with iTerm2. I invoke PowerShell via `pwsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, double quotes are stripped. Thus,

```
split("\n") | map(split("\t")) | .[0:-1]
```

becomes

```
split(\n) | map(split(\t)) | .[0:-1]
```

Edit: as per the comment, in this case, doubling the double quote works. No backtick escape is used:

```
split(""\n"") | map(split(""\t"")) | .[0:-1]
```

Usually it's worth of trying Powershell's escape character, backtick `` ` ``, to escape double quotes like so,

```
split(`"\n`")
```

(Which doesn't work in this particular case. Shell escapes can be tricky.)

Comment: Thank you!  split(`"\n`") | map(split(`"\t`")) | .[0:-1] did not work but split(""\n"") | map(split(""\t"")) | .[0:-1].   Would you update your answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I only had to put double quotes on the split functions, not the keys within the map function.  Thank you for leading me down the right path!